# How to convert a hh:mm:ss to seconds without a time_string in python?

Tags: python, time

For my assignment the requirements are to state the function like this: 
`def to_seconds(hours, minutes, seconds):`

Most of the programs that I have seen run it with `time_str` between the parentheses. I have been attempting some different possibilities but I cannot seem to understand why my list doesn't want to convert to an integer so I can count all the individual variables.

Here is my code:

```
def to_seconds(hours, minutes, seconds):
  hh, mm, ss = str((hours * 3600, minutes * 60, seconds,)).split()
  return int(hh) + int(mm) + int(ss)
```

Comment: why are you turning it into a string? just perform the multiplications on the variables themselves

Comment: you can do something like this: `return hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds`

Comment: @StrangSorcerer I thought I had to do it in order to get the int and not the list itself. Turns out i shouldn't split it, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added unnecessary complication:
just do:

```py
def to_seconds(hours, minutes, seconds):
  return hours*3600 + minutes*60 + seconds
```

Your current error is:

```
hh = '(0,'
mm = '60,'
ss = '0)'
```

As you know we can't convert '(0,','60,' or '0)'  to int.

Comment: I see, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, I figured it out with help of the comments. This seems to be working for me:

```
def to_seconds(hours, minutes, seconds):
    hh, mm, ss = (hours * 3600, minutes * 60, seconds,)
    return int(hh) + int(mm) + int(ss)
```